# Declared variable not getting in javascript file, while setting condition with php if-else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made an accordion plugin in php wordpress. But in simple term with metabox value it giving the right ouput. but when i have set condition with php ifelse, it not giving right output. In console it giving there errors,

**Simple term:**

```
    var accor_close_icon = "<?= $accor_close_icon; ?>";
    var accor_expand_icon = "<?= $accor_expand_icon; ?>";
```

**Myset Condition**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


     <?php if(!empty($accor_close_icon)) { ?> 

     var accor_close_icon = "<?= $accor_close_icon; ?>";

      <?php } else { ?> 

      var accor_close_icon ="fa-minus";

       <?php } ?>

      
      <?php if(!empty($accor_expand_icon)) { ?>

       var accor_expand_icon = "<?= $accor_expand_icon; ?>";
        
        <?php} else {?> 

        var accor_expand_icon ="fa-minus";

         <?php } ?>

 
    //var accor_close_icon = "<?= $accor_close_icon; ?>";
    //var accor_expand_icon = "<?= $accor_expand_icon; ?>";

    console.log(accor_expand_icon);

    console.log(accor_close_icon);


</script>
```

**The javascript file:**

```
jQuery(".plugin_accor li h5").click(function () {
  var current_li = jQuery(this).parent();
  jQuery(".plugin_accor li div").each(function(i,el) {      
    if(jQuery(el).parent().is(current_li)) {       
      if (jQuery(el).is(":visible")) {
        jQuery(el).prev().toggleClass("plus "+accor_close_icon).toggleClass(""+accor_expand_icon);
        jQuery(el).slideUp().removeClass("plus");
      } else {
         jQuery(el).prev().toggleClass("plus "+accor_close_icon).toggleClass(""+accor_expand_icon);
         jQuery(el).slideDown().addClass("plus")
      }
    } else{
      jQuery(el).prev().removeClass("plus "+accor_close_icon).addClass(""+accor_expand_icon);
      jQuery(el).slideUp();
    }
  });
});

jQuery('.plugin_accor li > div').hide();
jQuery('.plugin_accor li h5').first().addClass(accor_close_icon+" plus").removeClass(""+accor_expand_icon);
jQuery('.plugin_accor li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
```

**Errors when set condition:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: accor_close_icon is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: accor_expand_icon is not defined

The values are not getting in javascript file. Is there any solution...

Comment: Sounds like the PHP code is being interpreted as HTML (JS) rather than going through PHP first

Comment: is there any solution.

Comment: make sure the file extension is php and make sure if php is running on your device/server . Also Check the source of output page and check if PHP tags are interpreted or still visible?

Comment: if else file extension is .php file

Comment: if else condition working on same page <style type="text/css"> but not in <script type="text/javascript">